# how do I check and uncheck all checkbox in python?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcheckbox, qbuttongroup

how do I select all checkboxes in

```
 qbuttongroup
```

in python ?

```
    self.group = QtGui.QButtonGroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over them using the [`buttons()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#buttons) method:

```
def setAllButtonsChecked(self, checked=True)
    for button in self.group.buttons():
        button.setChecked(checked)
```